# Green function KMS boundary condition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, greens-functions, many-body-physics

How to obtain the relation between $G_{ab}(\tau,0,0,0)$ and $G_{ab}(\beta-\tau,0,0,0)$ for two-particle fermion Green function
$$G_{ab}(\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3,\tau_4)=\langle \mathcal{T}a^\dagger(\tau_1)a(\tau_2)b^{\dagger}(\tau_3)b(\tau_4)\rangle$$ where $0<\tau<\beta$?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago but just wanted to check how things are going now. Did you figure this out? Are you still working on it?